# iPhone: open also a 3G socket when WiFi is active

Tags: objective-c, wifi, iphone-3gs

When the device is connected via WiFi, is there a way in iOS 6+ to open a socket in 3G?
For example, if the quality of the WiFi is not too good and I want to establish a connection via 3G network, even if I already have an open WiFi socket.